# Does the function $x^2 \sin({1 \over x})$ have a tangent at $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the function $f(x)$ defined by $x^2 \sin({1 \over x})$. Remove the discontinuity at $0$ by setting $f(0)$ to $0$. This function is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, and it seems differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^\times$ (ie. $\mathbb{R}$ without the origin).

Is it differentiable at $0$? Equivalently, does this function have a tangent line at $0$? Intuitively, it seems to me that, near $0$, it wiggles like crazy (at smaller and smaller scales), and the wiggles never "settle down", in the sense that, if you try to construct the tangent to the graph (passing through $(0, f(0))$ by using secants (passing through $(0, f(0))$ and $(0+\delta, f(0+\delta))$ , and letting $\delta\to 0$), your secants will never converge to the tangent (which, if it exists, I think should be the constant line $y=0$).

Is this correct?

Comment: The wiggles never settle down, but they do "smooth out" in the sense that their heights divided by their distances to $0$ approach a limit (zero, in fact). Remember, to examine differentiability at $0,$ you consider the heights divided by *distances to the origin*. The heights wind up being very tiny compared to their distances to the origin. You can see this by noticing that the graph lies between the graph of $y = x^2$ and the graph of $y=-x^{2}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$

$$\frac {f (x)-f (0)}{x-0}=x\sin (\frac {1}{x}   )$$

but

$$|x\sin ( \frac {1}{x} )|\leq |x|$$

$$\implies $$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin (\frac {1}{x}   )=0$$
$$\implies $$
$f $ is diffetentiable at $x=0$ and

$$f'(0)=0$$.

Comment: I think you wrote $x \sin\Big(\frac{1}{x} \Big)$ instead of $x^2 \sin\Big(\frac{1}{x} \Big)$, the argument works in the exact same way though

Comment: @Chris: the expressions written in the answer are correct. You are perhaps mistaken.

Comment: So the function $g$ that describes the slope of the secant of $f$ as $x\to 0$ is $g(x)  = x \sin({1 \over x})$, but $g$ converges to $0$ at $x=0$. Therefore, the slope of the secant also converges to $0$ at $x=0$. Is this what your argument means?

Comment: Also, the function $g(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ converges to $0$ at $x=0$ but it's undefined at $x=0$. How can this mean that the original function $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$) is differentiable at $0$, if $g$ isn't defined at $0$?